# jquery remove table from string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to refresh the contents of a box (div) only if anything changes. I got that working for a standard box with no jquery graphs however I now need to do the same for a box (div) which is modified by jquery to draw some graphs and it also inserts a table. 
I'm getting the contents of the current box using

```
var someBox = $('div#someBox').html();
```

I now need to remove the entire table (inc the contents) from 'someBox' but not the div itself. How can I do this using jquery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `remove()` function to completely remove an element and it's contents:

```
var somebox = $('div#someBox');
somebox.find('table#tableId').remove();
```

**NOTE**

If, in any case, you want to remove **only** the contents of an element, you can use `empty()` like this:

```
//Removes the contents of the table but NOT the table itself
somebox.find('table#tableId').empty();
```

Comment: thanks, I've tried that however I get the following error: uncaught TypeError: somebox.find is not a function

Comment: Set this: var somebox = $('div#someBox'); (remove the .html() part)

Comment: this is what I have now 
var someBox= $('div#someBox');
someBox = $(someBox).find('table').remove(); 

however it doesn't output the contents of the div now, it just comes up with 

table.table.table-hover.no-margins, table, prevObject: n.fn.init[1], context: document, selector.....

Comment: Remove "someBox =", just execute the function: someBox.find('table').remove();

Comment: it works in the following order: 1: someBox = someBox.find('table').remove(); then 2: someBox = someBox.html();